# Get data from mongo with a time duration

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some data like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ec8023d8db8712ffc831d56"},"acc_data":[[5,41,6],[10,2,65]],"time":{"$date":"1970-01-19T09:09:32.881Z"},"record_id":1899,"device":{"$oid":"5ec800c23ebdb84578124e9a"},"__v":0}
```

This data is very big (eg: in every minute, up to 2000 records may be inserted).

I want to get data between two date, its okay, but I want to get data that have 60000ms time interval or 30000ms ...

eg:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ec8023d8db8712ffc831d56"},"acc_data":[[5,41,6],[10,2,65]],"time":{"$date":"1970-01-19T09:09:32.881Z"},"record_id":1899,"device":{"$oid":"5ec800c23ebdb84578124e9a"},"__v":0}

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ec8023d8db8712ffc831d56"},"acc_data":[[5,41,6],[10,2,65]],"time":{"$date":"1970-01-19T09:10:32.881Z"},"record_id":1899,"device":{"$oid":"5ec800c23ebdb84578124e9a"},"__v":0}
```

What is the best way for do something like this?

Comment: Date value `1970-01-19T09:09:32.881Z` looks very unusual. Are you sure you inserted data correctly? Note, in JavaScript/MonogDB a Date value is number of **Milli**seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00Z` whereas Unix uses **Seconds** since `1970-01-01 00:00:00Z`. Perhaps you forgot to multiply input value by 1000.

Comment: Whenever one has to deal with Date/Time values, I suggest to use [Monemnt.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) library. This should provide all you need.